# How is relative scale calculated from an image sequence?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to estimate camera pose (with scale) from a 2D sequence. I use the following code to estimate the relative pose for each adjacent pair of images in my sequence:

```
Mat essentialMatrix = findEssentialMat(pointsB, pointsA, focalLength, principlePoint, RANSAC, 0.999, 1.0, mask);
recoverPose(essentialMatrix, pointsB, pointsA, rotationEstimate, translationEstimate, focalLength, principlePoint);
```

pointsA and pointsB are the 2D locations of features in frame A and frame B.

I would like to calculate the transformations for each frame, to obtain the world coordinate. To do this, I will be concatenating the relative pose matrices together. However, before concatenation I need to determine the relative scale.

My question is, how do I calculate the relative scale of relative poses in an image sequence? Can I utilize the solvePnPRANSAC API?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late though. But the simplest solution is to take a pair of images and two features in those. Then triangulate the features in respective images frames and then take the vector pointing from the first feature to the second one in the respective frames and take the ratios.I think that will solve the problem.